# Rails: Why are has_many relations not saved in the variable/attribute like belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So let's say I have the following models in Rails.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

When I put the Post instance in a variable and call `user` on it, the following sql query runs once, after that the result it is saved/cached.

```
post.user
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
#<User id: 1 ...>

post.user
#<User id: 1 ...>

etc.
```

However, when I go the other way around with `user.posts`, it always runs the query.

```
user.posts
Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 11

user.posts
Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 11

etc.
```

Unless I convert it to an array, in which case it does get saved.

```
user.posts.to_a 
Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 11

user.posts
# No query here.
```

But `user.posts` still produces a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` object on which I can call other activerecord methods. So no real downside here.

Why does this work like this? It seems like an unnecessary impact on sql optimization. The obvious reason I can think of is that `user.posts` updates correctly when a Post is created after `user` is set. But in reality that doesn't happen so much imo, since variables are mostly set and reset in consecutively ran Controller actions. Now I know there is a caching system in place that shows a `CACHE Post` sql in the server logs, but I can't really rely on that when I'm working with activerecord objects between models or with more complex queries.

Am I missing some best practice here? Or an obvious setting that fixes exactly this?

Answer (score 0):

You're examining this in `irb` and that's why you're seeing the query always running.

In an actual block of code in a controller or other class  if you were to write

```
@users_posts = user.posts
```

The query is NOT executed... not until you iterate through the collection, or request `#count`

`irb`, to be helpful, always runs queries immediately